# JavaScript RegEx splitting on math operators while keeping them as separate items

Tags: javascript, regex

I got strings like this

```
5 +var +"HEH"
5 +"HEllo!"
5
```

I need to parse it with RegEx, so as result I need to have an array

`['5', '+', 'var', '+', '"HEH"']`

`['5', '+', '"HEH"']`

`['5']`

I've tried something like

```
/(".+"|\d(?:\.\d+)*)(?:\s*(\+)\s*(".+"|\d(?:\.\d+)*|\w+))*/
```

But it returns only first matching group and last.

`['5', '+', '"HEH"']`

`['5', '+', '"HEllo!"']`

`['5']`

!Update
`.split()` can't be used because parsing values can be written without whitespaces. Sorry for not complete description

Comment: Cant you use `'5 + var + "HEH"'.split(' ')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why need a regex simply do with [`split()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwijoJX_vIDVAhVILI8KHVPKBT8QFgi2ATAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fsplit&usg=AFQjCNGVGuY9DfI9VAkeEZ1pZRBFS8cyUg)

```js
var a ='5 + var + "HEH"'

console.log(a.split(" "))
```

**Regex Method**  Try this pattern `(\d+)|"(\w+)"|(\w+)|(\+|-|\*|\/|=|>|<|>=|<=|&|\||%|!|\^|\(|\))`

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dZxy5X/3/)

Comment: This values can be written without whitespaces. E.G. "5+var+'heh'"

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```js
let str_1 = '5 + var + "HEH"';
let str_2 = '5 + "HEllo!"';
let str_3 = '5';
let regex = /\s([\+])\s/;

console.log(str_1.split(regex));
console.log(str_2.split(regex));
console.log(str_3.split(regex));
```

> The [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method splits a String object into an array of
>   strings by  separating the string into substrings.
>
> Syntax: `str.split([separator[, limit]])`
>
> The separator is treated as a string or a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use complex regex in any case. Try this -

First, replace all " +" with " + " and then use split method.

```
var str = '5 +var +"HEH"';
str.replace(/ \+/g, " + ");
```

Now use split() method -

```
console.log(str.split(" "));
```

```js
var str = '5 +var +"HEH"';
str = str.replace(/ \+/g, " + ");
console.log(str.split(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` with a regex matching and *capturing* all the math operators:

```js
s.split(/\s*([-\/*+=])\s*/)
```

Note the `=` sign is included here, you may remove it if you do not need to split on the equals sign.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const texts = ['5 +var +"HEH"','5 +"HEllo!"','5', '12+3-4='];
const regex = /\s*([-\/*+=])\s*/;
for (const text of texts) {
    console.log(text, "=>", text.split(regex));
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M7e0rG/1). Remember that [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) [pushes capturing group values](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to the resulting array:

> If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array.